# Extract part of string from list variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print(varName)
```

Output- `['name:  sourav\n' ]`

I want to extract only 'sourav' from the varName variable.

Can you guys kindly help, I am nub to python

Comment: Can you provide more examples of the input format?

Comment: Being a "nub" is NOT an excuse. Read documentation and study tutorials. Learn about `.split()`.

Comment: Really appreciate prompt replies.. found the solution with re.findall(r' : (\w+)', varName)

Comment: you do not need to use the re module, look at my solution, no modules need (much more simple too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is this:

```
    varName = "name: sourav\n"
    name = list(varName.split(": "))
    print(name[1])
```

This will output the name sourav.
Honestly, please do check documentation before asking questions but we will still be happy to help here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at `.split(split by)`
The split by is a string, or in this case ': '.

Also, look at `.strip(strip by)`
The strip by is a string, but it defaults to getting rid of the `\n` (newline) which is at the end of the name. Put these together and you can get the answer.

Examples:

```py
a = ['name: sourav\n']
b = a[0].split(': ')[1].strip()

print(b)
```

Note: Trying searching it up and looking at the documentation first, before posting a question on StackOverflow.